# Cannot use resque-web in Resque 2.0.0pre

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I just installed Resque 2.0.0pre, and cannot use `resque-web` anymore, it seems be removed from Resque.
My Gemfile definition:

```
gem "resque", "~> 2.0.0.pre.1", github: "resque/resque"
```

Does anyone also have this problem?

Comment: I had this problem as well, I have to manually go to http://localhost:6379

Comment: Ya, I've to download [resque-web](https://github.com/resque/resque-web) and run manually.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like resque-web has been [extracted](https://github.com/resque/resque/commit/b2ca4ceb9457242fc0170d95b3bce9d427baa387) to a new [`resque-web` repo](https://github.com/resque/resque-web).

However, I'm not sure if this new Rails' app can be mounted within another rails app, or if the idea is to deploy it as a separate application altogether.

I'm sure once Resque 2.0 is formally released there will be more info on how to migrate to this.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [resque-web](https://github.com/resque/resque-web) gem; making sure to follow the directions to mount the rescue-web routes in your config/routes file. Then try 'rake routes' to see the list of available routes.